# Can't figure out what datatype is incorrect in my SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-sequence

I am trying to create a SQL table, but I keep getting this error.

```
Error report -
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE viewers
(
    user_id     SEQUENCE    PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    last_name   VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR2(40) CHECK(LENGTH(email) > 8),
    DOB         DATE,
    CONSTRAINT contact_email UNIQUE (email)
);
```

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
    START WITH 100000   INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 100000     MAXVALUE 999999;
```

Comment: The available data types are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6). `SEQUENCE` isn't on the list.

Answer (score 4):

Your intention is correct but the usage syntactically is not.

You need to create the sequence as first step,

```
create sequence seq_user_id;

CREATE TABLE viewers
(
    user_id     number default seq_user_id.nextval PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    last_name   VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR2(40) CHECK(LENGTH(email) > 8),
    DOB         DATE,
    CONSTRAINT contact_email UNIQUE (email)
);
```

> *P.S. If you are using 12c and above then consider using `identity` column which is a nice feature. I am providing you the [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1).*